# How to hide/show div tags using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Basically, I'm trying to make a link that, when pressed, will hide the current body div tag and show another one in its place, unfortunately, when I click the link, the first body div tag still appears. Here is the HTML code:

```
<div id="body">
    <h1>Numbers</h1>
</div>
<div id="body1">
    Body 1
</div>
```

Here is the CSS code:

```
#body {
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto auto;
    border: solid medium thick;
}

#body1 {
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto auto;
    border: solid medium thick;
    display: hidden;
}
```

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
function changeDiv() {
  document.getElementById('body').style.display = "hidden"; // hide body div tag
  document.getElementById('body1').style.display = "block"; // show body1 div tag
  document.getElementById('body1').innerHTML = "If you can see this, JavaScript function worked"; // display text if JavaScript worked
}
```

NB: CSS tags are declared in different files

Answer (score 33):

Have you tried

`document.getElementById('body').style.display = "none";`

instead of

`document.getElementById('body').style.display = "hidden";`?

Answer (score 9):

just use a jquery event listner , click event.
let the class of the link is lb... i am considering body as a div as you said...

```
$('.lb').click(function() {
    $('#body1').show();
    $('#body').hide();
 });
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the following code:

```
function hide {
document.getElementById('div').style.display = "none";
}
function show {
document.getElementById('div').style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `jQuery`. Life is much easier with:

```
$('body').hide(); $('body1').show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Hide/Show Div using Js function. sample below

```
   <script>
        function showDivAttid(){

            if(Your Condition)
            {
             document.getElementById("attid").style.display = 'inline';
            }
            else
            {
            document.getElementById("attid").style.display = 'none';
            }

        }

    </script>
```

HTML - 
         Show/Hide this text

Answer (score 1):

Set your HTML as

```
 <div id="body" hidden="">
 <h1>Numbers</h1>
 </div>
 <div id="body1" hidden="hidden">
 Body 1
 </div>
```

And now set the javascript as

```
     function changeDiv()
      {
      document.getElementById('body').hidden = "hidden"; // hide body div tag
      document.getElementById('body1').hidden = ""; // show body1 div tag
      document.getElementById('body1').innerHTML = "If you can see this, JavaScript function worked"; 
      // display text if JavaScript worked
       }
```

Check, it works.

Answer (score -3):

> try yo write 
>   document.getElementById('id').style.visibility="hidden";

Comment: Probably style.visibility ?