# Switchable table by pressing button

Tags: html, css, button

How can I make a switchable table with buttons to lead to different view of another table? Something like this:

[image]

As you can see, once you click on the buttons it takes you to another table list.

Here is a base: http://jsbin.com/agavid/136/edit

Need something similar to this.

Comment: You could have 6 `.html` files, which just contain the individual tables. Then using `Javascript`, make an `AJAX` request when you click on a button, and pull in the new table content?

Answer (score 2):

You can create several different tables and use a simple JS/jQuery script to show and hide the tables based on which button is pressed.

Essentially you would show all tables at start (for progressive enhancement), then hide all of them except the first one. Then when a button is clicked, hide all the tables and show only the one associated with that button.

Here's a demo of what I'm talking about. http://jsfiddle.net/7Ywbn/2/

```
(function () {
var tables = $("table");
//Grabs all the tables
tables.hide().first().show();
//Hides all the tables except first
$("a.button").on("click", function () {
    //Adds eventListner to buttons
    tables.hide();
    //Hides all the tables
    var tableTarget = $(this).data("table");
    //Gets data# of button
    $("table#" + tableTarget).show();
    //Shows the table with an id equal to data attr of the button
})
})();
```

Hope I understood your question correctly.

Comment: great js fiddle example.

Answer (score 1):

here is a suggestion

wrap each table in a `<div id="table1">` `<div id="table2">` etc.. and hide them all by default. here is some help on that: [hiding div using js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260418/how-to-hide-show-div-tags-using-javascript)

and then only show the `<div>` for the table associated with the button the user has clicked on. you can do this using javascript, jquery as a couple examples.

you may need to start looking into learning some basic javascript/jquery if you don't already know any, you are going to need it.

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could create multiple divisions within the same file and hide all the divisions except the primary you want to display during the initial page load.  then use "onClick='showNextDiv();" inside the buttons themselves.

A sample of the javascript would be:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js'></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict()
function showNextDiv() {
  document.getElementById('DivName').style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('FirstDiv').style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

All this is saying that when someone clicks on a button this script runs and displays the 'DivName' div.  That's what "block" means.  It also turns off the division "FirstDiv" by using the "none".

You can add as many "block" and/or "none" statements to the script.  If you have 6 divisions you would want to display one and turn off 5.

I hope this is helpful.  I'm not an expert at this but it works fine for me.